# Как по клику на элемент массива, который лежит в объекте, получать значение которое лежит в том же объекте?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Суть в чём, есть у меня такой массив(динамический) с объектами и мне по клику на username(всех юзеров я вывожу списком на странице) нужно получать ссылку из callLink и переходить по ней. Я написал eventListener, но работает нормально только для первых двух юзеров, а если больше двух, то берёт только последнего юзера. Буду безумно благодарен за помощь, заранее спасибо!

Вот массив из объектов:

```
(2) […]
​
0: {…}
​​
 callLink: "https://cop.com:4001/call/test/1595255422465-5390645"
​​
 counter: 1
​​
 id: "1595255422465-5390645"
​​
 username: "User (352488)"
​
1: {…}
​​
 callLink: "https://cop.com:4001/call/test/1595255510042-8293766"
​​
 counter: 3
​​
 id: "1595255510042-8293766"
​​
 username: "User (411293)"

length: 2
```

Вот мой eventListener:

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.user-call') || [];

items = Array.from(items)
console.log(items.map(el => {
  console.log(el.innerText)
}), '<------item')
items = [...new Map(items.map(item => [item.innerText, item])).values()]
console.log(items)

items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let target = e.target.textContent

    window.open(callLink, target, 'scrollbars=no, ' +
      'resizable=no, status=no, location=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, ' +
      'width=320, height=240, left=100, top=screen.height-240')
  })
})
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, откуда вы берете callLink? Он у вас в атрибутах? В коде он у вас никак не определяется, но фигурирует. Кроме этого, вы из массива JS объектов извлекаете html элементы, на которые хотите повесить обработчики. Строки 3 и 5 не несут никакого смысла, т.к. querySelectorAll возвращает массив JS Объектов, на которые вам и следует вешать обработчики клика.

Comment: @xydope, `querySelectorAll` возвращает не массив.

Comment: @Grundy Да, в этом неправ.

Comment: @xydope, пятая строчка тоже нужна, судя по всему она призвана удалить из списка элементы у которых дублируется  `innerText`

Comment: @Grundy  мне не очень понятно, зачем получать список элементов через querySelectorAll (который и так можно перебрать через forEach), преобразовывать его в массив и перебирать через forEach. Мне это не кажется логичным. Видимо, на вкус и цвет...

Comment: @xydope, конкретно в данной задаче - непонятно, но если брать только блок с js - то выглядит вполне осмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того, где у вас хранится callLink после создания html элементов на странице.
В целом, можете отталкиваться от нескольких возможных вариантов.

- callLink никак не сохраняется, а так и хранится в исходном массиве. После клика по объекту выполняется функция, которая находит в исходном массиве юзера по ID/username и выдергивает его callLink.
- При создании html элементов, вы сохраняете callLink в атрибутах элемента и уже с ним работаете.
- Как мне кажется, самый корректный вариант, еще в момент создания элементов, нужно создавать обработчики, в которые сразу прокидывать callLink (см. пример).

```js
users = [{
    id: 1,
    username: "user1",
    callLink: "user1 callLink"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    username: "user2",
    callLink: "user2 callLink"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    username: "user3",
    callLink: "user3 callLink"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    username: "user4",
    callLink: "user4 callLink"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    username: "user5",
    callLink: "user5 callLink"
  }
]

let root = document.getElementById("root");

users.map(item => {
  let user = document.createElement("div")
  user.textContent = item.username;
  user.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert(item.callLink);
  })
  root.appendChild(user);
})
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: вместо map лучше forEach или reduce, чтобы не создавался новый массив

Comment: чем? Ок, forEach ничего не возвращает, но reduce-то чем лучше в этих условиях? Больше аргументов писать? :)

Comment: reduce - точно так же не создает новый массив, плюс логически он тут больше подходит, так как происходит свертка массива users в один контейнер `root`. А это прямое назначение метода `reduce` - свертка массива

Comment: Разве не логичней тогда все же использовать forEach, который ничего не возвращает? В то время, как reduce возвращает аккумулятор, который по сути и является результатом свертки, мы же используем reduce лишь как итератор и аккумулятор просто отбрасываем (ровно как и результативный массив в map).

Comment: нет, не логичней ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ :-) аккумулятор не отбрасывается, так как он _уже есть_ и в отличие от массива, возвращаемого методом map - используется.

Comment: не понял, как он используется? Мы же лишь перебираем массив и на основе его элементов создаем новые html элементы. Как у нас аккумулятор используется? Не могли бы вы пример привести (схематично)? users.reduce((acc, item)=>(создаем html элементы, вешаем обработчики, что передаем дальше?), каково начальное значение аккумулятора?), как используем результирующее значение аккумулятора?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110827/discussion-between-grundy-and-xydope).